# Is there a way to see Desktop Events vs Mobile Events in Google Analytics like it does Goals?

Tags: google-analytics, mobile, event-tracking

In Google Analytics in the Mobile Overview it shows Desktop / Mobile / Tablet and has columns for conversions/goals. Most of our setup is using Event triggers not linked to any Goal though. For example downloading our product catalog as a .pdf triggers an Event.

Is there a way to see these events in the Mobile Overview or only if I tie each one to its own goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see specified actions (events) on your website as conversions and goals in GA, then you'll need to [set up Event Goals](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032720?hl=en-GB) so these are registered as so yes.

Comment: Was giving this time to see if anyone else had an answer but guess this is it. That's unfortunate.